# Что делать с выбросами дальше на примере Isolation Forest

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, анализ-данных, scikit-learn, обработка-данных

В инструкции по sklearn есть пример по обнаружению выбросов IsolationForest:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.RandomState(42)

# Generate train data
X = 0.3 * rng.randn(100, 2)
X_train = np.r_[X + 2, X - 2]
# Generate some regular novel observations
X = 0.3 * rng.randn(20, 2)
X_test = np.r_[X + 2, X - 2]
# Generate some abnormal novel observations
X_outliers = rng.uniform(low=-4, high=4, size=(20, 2))  

# fit the model
clf = IsolationForest(max_samples=100, random_state=rng)
clf.fit(X_train)
y_pred_train = clf.predict(X_train)
y_pred_test = clf.predict(X_test)
y_pred_outliers = clf.predict(X_outliers)

y_pred_outliers
```

Выбросы мы обнаружили, а что дальше с ними делать я не понял) Нужно их как-то удалить перед обучением моделей - что улучшит качество, или что с ними делать и для чего их вообще искать, подскажите, пожалуйста, или поделитесь документацией, где можно подробнее про это прочитать. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Обнаружение выбросов/аномалий может быть самостоятельной задачей. Например, вы хотите выявить неправильную работу оборудования/датчиков (в нештатном режиме), или хакерские атаки, или какие-то некорректные данные (чтобы дополнительно проанализировать что с ними не так) или, скажем, погодные аномалии... Применений можно много придумать. А вообще это называется [выявление аномалий (anomaly detection)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9). В этом случае вы их просто находите в данных и дальше что-то делаете именно с этими аномалиями, остальные данные вас уже не интересуют.
- Но в принципе, можно этот метод применять и для чистки данных для использования в простых (линейных, например) моделях. Большинство сложных моделей в той или иной мере устойчивы к аномалиям, но бывают случаи, когда предпочтение отдаётся простым моделям (они и быстрее работают и лучше интерпретируются), тогда данные нужно чистить и да, в этом случае обнаруженные аномалии можно исключать из данных перед их использованием в линейной модели. Но делать это нужно осторожно, аномалия - понятие неоднозначное, можно легко "выплеснуть с водой ребёнка". Всегда нужно смотреть метрики обучения, бывает так, что и простые модели начинают хуже предсказывать, если исключить аномалии. Возможно, это бывает в том случае, когда аномалии - не такие уж и аномалии, а нормальные вполне данные, просто вот такие сильно отличающиеся от общего фона.